# Where to download the PyQt4 class reference?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, reference

Is there an offline version of this PyQt4 class reference: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/classes.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On debian based systems, there is a package called `python-qt4-doc` you can just install it via `sudo apt-get install python-qt4-doc`.

Then the documentation is found in

`/usr/share/doc/python-qt4-doc/html/index.html`

and the class reference is

`/usr/share/doc/python-qt4-doc/html/classes.html`

Answer (score 0):

Windows users can also download `python-qt4-doc` package ([from this link, for example](https://packages.debian.org/stable/all/python-qt4-doc/download)) and extract the .deb content with file archiver software, like 7-zip